# show message on untouched and submit angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="text" ng-model="job" required class="form-control" name="job">
<span ng-show="myForm.job.$touched && myForm.job.$invalid">
</span>

<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="myForm.$valid && submitUser()">Done
</button>
```

I want to show message on  both untouched and button click, but it is showing only on touched and also form must not be submitted as it is working.

Comment: try using `myForm.job.$pristne` or `myForm.job.$dirty.`

Comment: no,it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$submitted` in a below combination, but for the same you to `submit` form, that you're not doing. So

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && submitUser()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="job" required class="form-control" name="job">
    <span ng-show="(myForm.job.$touched || myForm.$submitted) && myForm.job.$invalid">
       My Error
    </span>

    ...
    ...

    <button class="btn" type="submit">Done</button>

</form>
```

Comment: @ravneet you could use that, you have to make button `type="submit"` and then shift `ng-click` to `ng-submit` on form level..

Comment: @ravneet it seems like something is misunderstood.. can you please explain in details what exactly should happen? Otherwise noone could help

Comment: i want to show error for both touched and button click..touched is working..but on button click it shows nothing.. and don't submit form if it is invalid

Comment: @ravneet hey I have already read you question.. I didn't asked you to copy and paste question text here in comment.. 
Please elaborate what exactly you need...

Answer (score 0):

First change your button code to this:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="submitUser()">Done</button>
```

change your span code to

```
<span ng-show="myForm.job.$touched || buttonClicked">
```

### In your Controller:

```
$scope.buttonClicked = false; // Set it to false on initial load
$scope.submitUser = function(){
    ..................
    $scope.buttonClicked = true;
    ..................
}
```

Comment: you want to show message when user has not touched the field and clicks submit right?

Comment: your exact case is that, you want to show required error that you needs to input this field right?

Comment: i want to show error for both touched and button click..touched is working..but on button click it shows nothing..

Comment: My personal advice is: It is bad user experience to show messages on touched, instead use dirty. But if you want to stay with touched, I have edited my code. It will work now.

Comment: you mean you want to show message after form is submitted? or u want to stop submitting form here?

Comment: I am doing same functionality for my forms as well.
For this I have made a common FormValidation Method and check it on submit, and in that method I set fields to touched which are empty, and in this common method returns true or false on basis that all fields are touched or not. 
and In controller , I check if form is not valid return; it will prevent from submitting form and all of your fields will be set to touched. I will show error and in the mean time it will prevent from submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
<input type="text" ng-model="job" required class="form-control" name="job">

<span ng-show="(myForm.job.$untouched  || myForm.$invalid)">

<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="myForm.$valid && submitUser()">Done</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `$touched` in the input elements and button click evaluated using a variable.

```js
var ang = angular.module("app", []);
ang.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
 $scope.submitUser =  function(){
    
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script> 
<div ng-app="app">
<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" name="job" ng-model="job" required class="form-control" >
<span ng-show="myForm.job.$touched ||show">Error</span>
<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="myForm.$valid ? submitUser() : (show=true)">Done</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the button to set the `$touched` status of the control:

```
<button class="btn" type="button"
        ng-click="myForm.job.$setTouched(); myForm.$valid && submitUser()">Done
</button>
```

Then the message will show when the button is clicked.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/sN7lkm1vIqlrZChIcMCw?p=preview)

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app>
    <h1>myForm</h1>
    <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="job" 
      required class="form-control" name="job">
<span ng-show="myForm.job.$touched && myForm.job.$invalid">
     Enter valid job
</span>

     <button class="btn" type="button"
             ng-click="myForm.job.$setTouched(); myForm.$valid && submitUser()">Done
     </button>
  </form>  
  <br>myForm.job.$touched = {{myForm.job.$touched}}
  <br>myForm.job.$invalid = {{myForm.job.$invalid}}
  </body>
```